# tryCatch does not catch an error if called though RScript

Tags: r, try-catch

I'm facing a strange issue in R.

Consider the following code (a really simplified version of the real code but still having the problem) :

```
library(timeSeries)

tryCatch(
{
  specificWeekDay <- 2

  currTs <- timeSeries(c(1,2),c('2012-01-01','2012-01-02'),
                       format='%Y-%m-%d',units='A')
  # just 2 dates out of range
  start <- time(currTs)[2]+100*24*3600
  end <- time(currTs)[2]+110*24*3600

  # this line returns an empty timeSeries
  currTs <- window(currTs,start=start,end=end)

  message("Up to now, everything is OK")

  # this is the line with the uncatchable error
  currTs[!(as.POSIXlt(time(currTs))$wday %in% specificWeekDay),] <- NA

  message("I'm after the bugged line !")

},error=function(e){message(e)})

message("End")
```

When I run that code in RGui, I correctly get the following output:

> Up to now, everything is OK
>   error in evaluating the argument 'i' in
>   selecting a method for function '[<-': Error in
>   as.POSIXlt.numeric(time(currTs)) : 'origin' must be supplied
>   End

Instead, when I run it through RScript (in windows) using the following line:

```
RScript.exe --vanilla "myscript.R"
```

I get this output:

> Up to now, everything is OK
>   Execution interrupted

It seems like RScript crashes...

Any idea about the reason?
Is this a timeSeries package bug, or I'm doing something wrong ?
If the latter, what's the right way to be sure to catch all the errors ?

Thanks in advance.

---

**EDIT :**

Here's a smaller example reproducing the issue that doesn't use timeSeries package. To test it, just run it as described above:

```
library(methods)
# define a generic function
setGeneric("foo", 
           function(x, ...){standardGeneric("foo")})
# set a method for the generic function
setMethod("foo", signature("character"),
          function(x) {x})
tryCatch(
{
  foo("abc")
  foo(notExisting)
},error=function(e)print(e))
```

It seems something related to generic method dispatching; when an argument of a method causes an error, the dispatcher cannot find the signature of the method and conseguently raises an exception that `tryCatch` function seems unable to handle when run through RScript.
Strangely, it doesn't happen for example with `print(notExisting)`; in that case the exception is correctly handled.

Any idea about the reason and how to catch this kind of errors ?

Note:
I'm using R-2.14.2 on Windows 7

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The issue is in the way the internal C code implementing S4 method dispatch tries to catch and handle some errors and how the non-interactive case is treated in this approach. A work-around should be in place in R-devel and R-patched soon.

Work-around now committed to R-devel and R-patched.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! And thank you for all your work on the R core team.

Comment: An answer direclty from the R-core team :O  Thank you so much Luke !! :)

Comment: Does anyone know if this was fixed? I couldn't find the bug report in the R bugzilla? I'm getting the same error on Linux using R 2.15.0. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

### Information about `tryCatch()` [that the OP already knew and used but I didn't notice]

I think you are missing that your `tryCatch()` is *not* doing anything special with the error, hence you are raising an error in the normal fashion. In interactive use the error is thrown and handled in the usual fashion, but an error inside a script run in a non-interactive session (a la `Rscript`) will abort the running script.

`tryCatch()` is a complex function that allows the potential to trap and handle all sorts of events in R, not just errors. However by default it is set up to mimic the standard R error handling procedure; basically allow the error to be thrown and reported by R. If you want R to do anything other than the basic behaviour then you need to add a specific handler for the error:

```
> e <- simpleError("test error")
> tryCatch(foo, error = function(e) e,
+          finally = writeLines("There was a problem!"))
There was a problem!
<simpleError in doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler): object 'foo'
not found>
```

I suggest you read `?tryCatch` in more detail to understand better what it does.

An alternative is to use `try()`. To modify your script I would just do:

```
# this is the line with the uncatchable error
tried <- try(currTs[!(as.POSIXlt(time(currTs))$wday %in% specificWeekDay),] <- NA,
             silent = TRUE)
if(inherits(tried, "try-error")) {
    writeLines("There was an error!")
} else {
    writeLines("Everything worked fine!")
}
```

The key bit is to save the object returned from `try()` so you can test the class, and to have `try()` operate silently. Consider the difference:

```
> bar <- try(foo)
Error in try(foo) : object 'foo' not found
> bar <- try(foo, silent = TRUE)
> class(bar)
[1] "try-error"
```

Note that in the first call above, the error is caught **and** reported as a message. In the second, it is not reported. In both cases an object of class `"try-error"` is returned.

Internally, `try()` is written as a single call to `tryCatch()` which sets up a custom function for the error handler which reports the error as a message and sets up the returned object. You might wish to study the R code for `try()` as another example of using `tryCatch()`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I don't think I totally got you. I mean, I have set an handler for the errors (i.e. error=function(e){message(e)}) so, when an error is encountered it should call this function and stop the evaluation of the expression, right ? (and it actually does, excluding this particular case). Perhaps the exception that I'm encountering does not inherit from error class ?

Comment: Apologies; I totally missed that line in your code. I can reproduce this, even if I replace your error bit with the `simpleError` from my Answer. Interestingly, if you substitute `try` for `tryCatch`, comment out the `error = ....` part of the call and add in `silent = TRUE`, your script *does* work fine via `source()` in an running R session and via `Rscript`. Must be something specific to what you are doing; I tried an example based on my Answer (but not using your example) and it worked fine with RScript. I wonder if `timeSeries` is doing something outwith the usual error handling?

Comment: don't worry about it :) About the error I don't know, I'm also starting to think timeSeries is doing something strange with the error...

Comment: Hmm, seems to be that the error thrown is in `as.POSIXlt.numeric()` but quite why that is being treated differently is anyones guess.